# From input of one textfield autofill the other textfield using jQuery or JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX and JSON. I stug from last three days in it. Basically I have a form with five text fields. If the user enters item-name or item-id in the textfield the other text field will autofill from the database through AJAX/JSON.

form like

```
<form>
    <input type='text' name='item-id' />
    <input type='text' name='item-name' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='tax' />
    <input type='text' name='price' />

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

Also if the user increases the quantity field, then all the other fields should update automatically, that increase the price and tax rate. Please guide me how can I call the PHP script and update these fields.

Comment: Read the jQuery docs on post() and serialize(). They will be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

Bind [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event to item-name (or item-id) with some timeout (so it fetches the data automatically after some time. No need to press ENTER or any other confirmation key) and use jQuery's [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) API to fetch the correct data. After that use the [Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) API to add correct values fetched from the ajax query to rest of the fields.

There are really good examples in the bottom of each page so be sure to scroll down!

Something like this:

```
var updateTimeout = null;

$("#item-name").keypress(function(event) {
    if(updateTimeout != null) {
        clearTimeout(updateTimeout);
    }

    updateTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        var item = $("#item-name").val() 
        autoFill(item);
    }, 1000); // 1000 = 1s
}   

function autoFill(itemName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl.php",
        data: "name=" + itemName
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#quantity").val(data["quantity"]);
            $("#tax").val(data["tax"]);
        });
}
```

Comment: i face problem in passing php array to json,please help